# How can I feed ruby on rails data into d3.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, d3.js

I'm currently having trouble figuring out how to feed a hash that I created in ruby on rails into javascript code that I am using with d3.js to create a line graph to show numerical values over time.

The hash is currently set up as { :date => value, :date => value, etc. }

I did .to_json to turn them into json but then I'm having a lot of trouble pulling these values in javascript to be the x and y values of my graph.

Could anyone please help point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Rails and everything with D3.js. Read the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki).

Comment: Yeah but I just don't know how to pull in external data that isn't in a txt file....., just a hash in ruby @p4sh4

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this ... you could do it with AJAX for example.

But here's a really simple way to do it:

```
<script>
  <% my_ruby_hash = { foo: "bar" } %>
  var jsonString = "<%= my_ruby_hash.to_json %>"
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonString)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the gon gem for generating similar graph with d3.js

In your gem file add gem gon

```
gem 'gon'
```

in your relevant controller for example I use index

```
def index
  data = 'some data in what ever format you like'
  gon.data = data
end
```

in your view you can access gon data and pass it to relevant javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  var dataset = gon.data;
  plot_graph(dataset);
  });
</script>
```